# Сокращение кода в одну

Tags: python

Можно ли как то эти строчки:

```
id = requests.get('').text
id = json.loads(id)
id = id[0]['id']
```

Сократить в одну?

Comment: Зачем это сокращать? Какую проблемы вы таким образом решите?

Comment: А толку? так вы легко все читаете, в чем имхо главное достоинство питона, ну соберете вы все это в одну о которою каждый раз будет спотыкаться взгляд и получится хрень... а быстродействия от этого не добавится.

Comment: Вы заснули, когда писали заголовок вопроса? что значит "сокращение кода в одну"? в одну что? строку, попытку, пятилетку?

Answer (score 2):

а так разве не работает?

```
id = json.loads(requests.get('').text)[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучшие все-таки в две строки, чтобы легче читалось. Вместо “json.loads()” лучше воспользоваться встроенным в request методом “.json()”:

```
data = requests.get('...').json()
ID = data[0]['id']
```

“id” - является встроенной функцией, не нужно использовать/затенять имена встроенных функций.